# Absolute position of items in an RDLC

Tags: .net, reporting-services, rdlc

I am working on a RDLC file that, when printed, will be printed to a pre-printed form on 8"x11" paper.  The form has two areas, one above the other, that contain tables of information.  These tables can have 1 - 10 rows of data in them.  On the form the tables have about 1/4" of space between them so I laid my report out like this: [image: Tables1]

This works fine if the top table has 10 rows of data in it, but the positioning of the tables is relative so this causes the bottom table to "slide up" when it is printed on the page.  I then tried to place my table inside of a rectangle like so: [image: Tables2]

The idea being that I only want the table to consume the area inside the rectangle.  The problem with this is that all of the whitespace inside of the rectangle is just tacked on to the end of where the table stops rendering. It seems like absolutely positing an element on a page should be straightforward but it is proving to be extremely difficult.  Can anyone provide any information on how to best solve my problem?  As a general FYI: I have consulted numerous SO and MSDN articles about this and none have been able to answer my question.

EDIT

Initially I fixed this problem by following a suggestion found in [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f329827b-e3e1-4774-8dde-b83b0efd43fb/how-to-fix-table-height-in-rdlc-report) thread.  Basically it involves setting a table on-top-of but not inside a rectangle.  This is hack to say the least.  The solution that Ian provided below is much more intuitive.

Comment: Have you looked at the report level ConsumeContainerWhitespace property?

Comment: Hey Ian.  I actually just solved this problem, although via different means.  Your solution is much more intuitive (and it does solve the problem), so if you create an answer I will mark it as being correct.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the update... Have added as an answer. I knew this existed for RDLs but didn't have time to check for RDLC files, hence just posting a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the report-level **ConsumeContainerWhitespace** property to control how empty space in containers like Rectangles is managed - if you set this to *True* this could help with your issue.